# Magento cart quantity not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, cart, jquery

A while ago I got into a company with a lot of problems in their Magento website, I have fixed a few major bugs in the website but I'm still stuck with this one bug.

This one is pretty common but for some reason ( as a Magento starter ) I can't seem to fix this bug.

I have seen a lot of posts containing the same fix but that fix does not seem to be available for me. Since they are all talking about editing `cart.phtml` in

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/

So they are all telling me to put `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

on line 50 after

`getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">`

But my file seems to contain more or less than it should have.
Here is my code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3759dc5742572d957825ab1c4a0172b3

[https://www.atwix.com/magento/common-issues-and-solutions-during-magento-upgrade-to-1-9/](https://www.atwix.com/magento/common-issues-and-solutions-during-magento-upgrade-to-1-9/%22This%20is%20the%20solution%20I%20keep%20finding%22)

I'm talking about **Updating cart items in the checkout page**
[image: Here is an example]

So whenever I press on "Winkelwagen bijwerken" ( update shopping cart ) it simply does nothing ( well it does seem to refresh the form but that's it )

So I would like to know if there is a way to fix this?

---

- Current version : Magento 1.9.3.1
- Previous version : Magento 1.8

**quick note** : There were other trainees who worked on this update

---

Comment: Is your form key being rendered on the page (in the html)?

Comment: @Joe To be honest, I don't know. as you can see on line 103 the button sents something to the core ( I think? a request of some sort?? )  `<button type="submit" name="update_cart_action"  value="update_qty" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Update Shopping Cart')); ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart'); ?></span></span></button>`

Comment: @Joe I am currently running on my default theme which I think is located in `design\frontend\default\default\template` however I hardly have any folders in this folder, my checkout folder and other folders are located in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template`  all of the guides are telling me to go to my own theme and edit cart.phtml and add a line after line 50 but I think my code is totally different or I am missing files.

Comment: View your source and search for "form_key". If it's there, you'll see an input element like <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="..." />.

Comment: There aren't many files in default\default; you can always download the source from magento.com to compare if you're not sure. If you're not familiar with Magento's fallback system, you should read up on it as it'll help you immensely. Basically, if it doesn't find the file in default/default, it'll fallback and use the one from base/default. So you can copy cart.phtml from base/default to default/default (or whatever package/theme you have configured) and edit it there.

Comment: @Joe I found a website helping me fixing a part of the problem, you see I am using a theme called modern, after checking this website and applying what's written in there [The fix?](https://www.bricksandmortarweb.com/magento-web-design/update-cart-working-magento-1-9/)  I realised it was fixing the cart quantity update for the default website theme. sadly the fix doesn't apply for the modern website. `app/design/frontend/rwd/` contains 2 folders for me, which are default and logincheck. I am guessing I need a seperate folder for my modern theme. sadly simply copy, paste and rename doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem, so after reading the code over and over again I noticed that I was missing my formkey in my `cart.phtml` which is located in : `/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/`

> on line 50 after getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">

paste the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```